# T-SQL Query works manually but not in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following query that works flawlessly when executing it manually. This passes some worker information from Table TRABAJADORES to PERSONAL.

```
INSERT INTO REPORTESDIARIOS.DBO.PERSONAL (DNI, Nombres, Apellidos, Contraseña, IdGrupo, Activo, Confianza)
    SELECT          
        CODTRAB, UPPER(NOMBRE), (UPPER(APEPAT) + ' ' + UPPER(APEMAT)),   
        ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', '1234'), 12, 1, 0
    FROM            
        PIL.DBO.TRABAJADORES
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ReportesDiarios.DBO.PERSONAL ON CODTRAB = DNI
    WHERE           
        DNI IS NULL
```

but when I use it inside a trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER COPYNONLISTED
ON TRABAJADORES 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO REPORTESDIARIOS.DBO.PERSONAL (DNI, Nombres, Apellidos, Contraseña, IdGrupo, Activo, Confianza)
        SELECT          
            CODTRAB, UPPER(NOMBRE), (UPPER(APEPAT) + ' ' + UPPER(APEMAT)), 
            ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', '1234'), 12, 1, 0
        FROM            
            PIL.DBO.TRABAJADORES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            ReportesDiarios.DBO.PERSONAL ON CODTRAB = DNI
        WHERE           
            DNI IS NULL
END
GO
```

it just inserts the id (which is DNI) and the other fields are blank.

ex.
Edit: ([This is what i get on SQL](http://postimg.org/image/dsz97tg5t/)

Table 1 (row that is not on table 2)

```
1, Samuel, Jackson, PASS, 1, 0
```

using the query manually copies the same thing

```
1, Samuel, Jackson, PASS, 1, 0
```

however if i use it inside a trigger it just copy the ID but everything else that involves a Query to TRABAJADORES it doesn't work it just returns me blank (" ") data

```
1,  ,  , PASS, 1,0
```

is there something I am missing, because I had a similar problem while using the inserted table (and I gave up that approach) so I'm not sure if there is a restriction within the table or with SQL.

Comment: Your trigger needs to utilize the inserted and/or deleted virtual tables. The way you have this coded it will insert every single row from that select statement every time a row is inserted or updated in the your base table. I highly doubt that is what you want. i suspect you only want the row(s) that were updated.

Comment: idk if you get points just by editing but @marc_s is annoying to get edited by things that doesnt make MUCH of a difference.

Comment: @SeanLange i was trying to do this trigger by using inserted tables but i had the same error, giving me just the Id but everything else in blank. tried that already and i dont know why, i thought i was using them wrong so i tried this aproach, so manually query works fine but it doesn't on trigger. Edit: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004252/insert-into-trigger-using-inserted)

Comment: @SeanLange and also the select statement gets me just the rows that are not on table B so if i have 3 rows in table A it will only copy those 3 rows to Table B, (dont really need the after update) i just wanted to try something there. my question is more why the trigger gives a blank instead of the name, i could end up doing this manually every now and then and it will be fine, but i would prefer to do this on a trigger

Comment: If the value from inserted is an empty string it is because you inserted an empty string. If you can post the ddl for the tables and an example update where you can recreate this problem I would be interested to see what is going on. As it is there just isn't anything to work with to help provide an answer.

Comment: [table a with data](http://pastebin.com/5a2v4VrJ) and [table b - destination](http://pastebin.com/1U3YfYVG) so  when i do the query manually the select part will get me the 2 rows on table A which they are not on table B since is empty when i do the insert part it gets filled as it supposed to, however if i do it as a trigger and do a new insert on the table A it just gets the error stated above filled with blanks.

Comment: You have a left join in your trigger and you are not utilizing inserted. From what you posted it is totally guessing what you are trying to do here. You seem to be inserting into Personal using some data from Personal? It just doesn't make sense to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to add workers info from Table A to Table B, but Table B already have some information about workers from Table A, so far so good?,  now i am not using inserted at all [tried it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341552/trigger-not-working-from-inserted-data) , but didn't work, on this question i am  searching values that are not on Table B from Table A, that i get it. and i pass the values from A to B just fine with the Query itself, but if i add this into a trigger After Insert, it won't work (i get just the value (id) but the other info gets blank).

Comment: So why are you doing a left join to Personal at all? You are NOT using any of the values from that table in your insert. This is really not a complicated problem but you have not done a good explaining what you are trying to do or demonstrate the problem. Try paring down your sample table to only the columns relevant. Are you wanting to only insert rows into Personal where they do not yet exist? It would make your query a lot clear if you referenced an alias in your column instead of just the name.

Comment: i don't know if there is another simpler method, however the Left Join to Personal is just to check if CODTRAB (from TRABAJADORES) exists in Personal (DNI), thats how i get the rows that are not in Personal. and i want to add on Personal the info that yet not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I finally understand what you are trying to do. You need to utilize the inserted and deleted virtual tables in your triggers but apparently you were having some issue with it. Your code was close but it was using TRABAJADORES as the base table instead of inserted. Notice I also added aliases to your query and reference each column starting with the alias. That makes things a LOT easier to determine which table a certain column belongs to.

```
create TRIGGER COPYNONLISTED
ON TRABAJADORES 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PERSONAL 
    (
        DNI
        , Nombres
        , Apellidos
        , Contraseña
        , IdGrupo
        , Activo
        , Confianza
    )
    SELECT          
        i.CODTRAB
        , UPPER(i.NOMBRE)
        , (UPPER(i.APEPAT) + ' ' + UPPER(i.APEMAT))
        , ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', '1234')
        , 12
        , 1
        , 0
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSONAL p ON i.CODTRAB = p.DNI
    WHERE p.DNI IS NULL
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i keep getting the same error. [Check this image](http://postimg.org/image/895slnq7j/) first Select is from the original table, and second one is from Personal. that's after using the trigger .

Comment: I used the tables you provided and this works perfectly. The ONLY way you can get empty strings in the Personal table is if those values are empty strings in the insert statement. The column names in your screen shot do not match the table definitions you provided.

Comment: It is the same definition i just made a short query to show the useful data, [Check the full definition](http://postimg.org/image/dsz97tg5t/)  as i said, there is data, but i just get blanks like is not doing the query, is there a way to "debug" the triggers if there is an error or something, or a misconfiguration in SQL.

Comment: What you are describing is simply not possible with the code I posted. UNLESS the row already exists in PERSONAL which means the insert will not insert a new row and you getting confused thinking it will update the existing row with new values.

Comment: How about you post the tables with the existing data. Then post an insert statement that causes the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Sean even if  i have an empty table on Personal, that's what it copies and that is my whole problem, because i don't know why my Trigger is acting like that. I've done lots of triggers with insert and ive read a lot on this site about it, and most of the answers are like yours, that's why i tried my aproach using the origin table directly, and the query works but it doesn't when activated by a trigger

Comment: What you describe is not possible unless there is another trigger on that table or something. The code I posted does exactly what you stated you want to happen. Unless you can post a more detailed set of data that replicates the issue there is nothing I can do here. I say it works, you say it doesn't.

Comment: i am not telling that it doesn't work but i am just showing what happens, and how can i overcome that, but it seems like mine is a special case, that can't be replicated. anyway thanks a lot Sean to give some thought to it (and no there is not more triggers, just the APP that inserts the data into the DB) ill choose your answer as valid.